# spark cogroup/join KeyValueGroupedDataset with Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

I have 2 datasets.
First has a number of rows with unique keys

```
ds1
key   val1   val2
1     a      1
2     a      2
3     b      3
4     c      3
```

In the second same key can be encountered many times.

```
ds2
key     val1     val2
1       x        x    
1       x        g    
2       u        h    
5       i        j
```

I need to join them, but the logic inside is too complicated for a simple join so instead I decided to use cogroup and iterate over the data.

```
val ds1 = df1.as[ds1].groupByKey(_.key)
val ds2 = df2.as[ds2].groupByKey(_.key)

ds2.cogroup(ds1)(
(k:String, ds2:Iterator[ds2], ds1:Iterator[ds1]) => {
  //some logic
}
)
```

The problem is I don't actually need to group ds1, because I know it holds unique keys, but cogroup doesn't accept the ds overwise. I know there is the fullOuterJoin in the RDD class, but it has worse performance as far as I know.

```
val rdd1 = df1.as[ds1].rdd.map(x => (x.key, x))
val rdd2 = df2.as[ds2].rdd.groupBy(_.key)

rdd2.fullOuterJoin(rdd1)
```

Would it actually affect the performance? What alternatives are there if so?

I'm using spark 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

In Spark performance majorly depend on how much data you are processing because always remember spark is a computational engine. The better you provide the data to the executor the better the performance would be.

Join is for simple queries where as co-group is for grouping the two data frames. There are different ways of improving the performance but in your case you can create two different data frames and then make a simple join[If your dataframe is big enough] . Although co-group is performing grouping in the same executor due to which its performance is always better.